# How to traverse a directory in eiffel?

Tags: eiffel

Simple

How can I get a list of the files that are inside directory using eiffel?

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
class CARPETAS

creation
    make

feature {NONE}

    make is
      local
          directory: DIRECTORY
          path: STRING
      do
          path := "." -- Current directory
          !!directory.scan_with(path)
          list_directory(directory)
      end

    list_directory(directory: DIRECTORY) is
      local
          i: INTEGER
      do
          std_output.put_string("Content of " + directory.path + "%N")
          from
              i := directory.lower
          until
              i > directory.upper
          loop
              std_output.put_string("%T" + directory.name(i) + "%N")
              i := i + 1
          end
      end
end
```

Comment: with recent version of Eiffel, I would recommend  to use   DIRECTORY.entries

<code>
    local
      p: PATH
    do 
        across dir.entries as ic loop
            p := ic.item.path
            -- then use interface of PATH, such as PATH.name 
        end
    end
</code>

Answer (score 3):

with recent version of Eiffel, I would recommend  to use   DIRECTORY.entries

```
local
    p: PATH 
do
    across dir.entries as ic loop
        p := ic.item.path
            -- then use interface of PATH, such as PATH.name 
    end
end
```

note that the base_extension library also provides DIRECTORY_VISITOR , which is helpful to iterate recursively on directories

Comment: Somewhere we can find an example of DIRECTORY_VISITOR?